# Metro Modern UI " Failed to create component" C# Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I was trying out the Metro UI to create a C# application so I was testing out the framework tools in a new project. I've followed the instructions from https://n-a-r-w-i-n.github.io/MetroSet-UI/#how-to-use, as well as watching youtube videos where they install it via the Package Manager Console. All result in the same error I have been getting when I try to add an item to the form. [Encountered Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS0lP.png)

After running the design view goes completely blank and I cannot edit or do anything in that regard. Here is the code used for Form1.

```
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MetroFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_App
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I have notices I also have this warning.

```
Severity: Warning
Code: NU1701

Description: Package 'MetroModernUI 1.4.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Project: Test App.csproj
Line: 1
```

Please assist me to get a hang of this! Thank you for your time in advanced! :)

Comment: Switch your target framework from `.NET Framework 4.x.x` to `.NET Core 3.1` and your problems will go away. (You'll probably want to create a new Project, as [porting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) can be a hassle)

Comment: Thanks for replying! How would I switch the target framework? @MindSwipe

Comment: Here's the .csproj file:
https://imgur.com/a/ppp4P2L